# Need help for a java runtime error - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl

I'm a newbie to Java, Maven and pretty much every Java library that I'm using. I've spent the last 4 hours trying to figure out this runtime error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.setWindowProc(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.setWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.<clinit>(WindowsDisplay.java:219)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createDisplayImplementation(Display.java:159)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:136)
    at game.Game.init(Game.java:148)
    at defaultPackage.CraftMania.main(CraftMania.java:52)
```

I don't think the code of `Craftmania.main` and `Game.init` is any useful, although feel free to ask for it and I will post it.

In my project I'm using Maven, here's the pom file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>org.craftmania</groupId>
        <artifactId>CraftMania</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <name>defaultPackage.CraftMania</name>
        <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
        <url>http://www.example.com</url>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
                <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
                <artifactId>lwjgl_util</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>java3d</groupId>
                <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
                <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
                <plugins>
                    <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/natives/windows/:${java.library.path}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                            </archive>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>conf/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>natives/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>res/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>defaultPackage.CraftMania</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </project>
```

I cannot figure out a fix to this. Could it be a mismatch between the .dll file (which was alredy in the project) and my version of lwjgl?

Just in case, here's what [my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMM3S.png) looks like. The src directory is `src/main/java/hereAreMyPackages`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a mismatch between the DLL and its JAR file.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: You find and use the correct version of the DLL.  Or the  version of the JAR that matches the DLL you are using.

Comment: Kinda solved, thanks.